# Invalid Memory Address with http.SetCookie

Tags: go, go-http

I am working on an auth package called persona.

Every thing works fine except one thing, when I try to set a cookie, I have an invalid memory address.

```
func Signup(user interface{}, username string, w http.ResponseWriter) error {
    key := []byte(randStringBytes(32))

    encrypted, err := encrypt(key, username)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    expiration := time.Now().Add(365 * 24 * time.Hour)
    cookie := http.Cookie{Name: "session-persona", Value: encrypted, Expires: expiration}
    http.SetCookie(w, &cookie)

    userSession := Session{Username: username, Key: key, Token: encrypted}
    database.Create(&userSession)

    database.Create(user)

    return nil
}
```

When I remove `http.SetCookie(w, &cookie)` everything works fine.
Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem might not be the `http.Cookie` object, but perhaps the `ResponseWriter` object (since `ResponseWriter` is an interface). For debugging, try checking it for `nil` before setting the Cookie. If it is `nil`, you’ll probably have to look up the stack from `Signup’ to figure out why - perhaps it had already been closed.